# Siebel Open UI and custom UI

Tags: oracle, user-interface, siebel

One of my customers uses Siebel CRM. They've asked me to work on a custom UI, but I don't specialise in Java.

Is it possible to somehow use the interface that Siebel Open UI uses (in for example JSON) to create a separate UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is not  a required skill for customizing Siebel's Open UI framework. The required skills are JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. The framework already provides complete flexibility for creating a custom user interface.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Duncan, **Javascript, HTML, CSS, JQuery, AJAX** is all you need to successfully design, deploy and maintain a Open UI related module in Siebel.

I've seen many senior Siebel developers who are not well versed with Javascript and UI concepts confusing with Java and Javascript. But the fact is that Java has nothing to do with Javascript and so is with Siebel Open UI.

Start learning the UI concepts from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) which has the very fundamentals necessary for you to begin with Open UI.

Understand the Application data flow in the Open UI application

- File System hierarchy in the Web Server (JS Files, CSS Files, SWT Template files, images)
- How the PM(Presentation Model), PR(Physical Renderer), PW(Plugin Wrapper) are used in the Open UI, and which requirement necessitates the use of these
- Learn AJAX, JSON, Rest API Concepts for fetching the backend data Asynchronously to the Siebel UI layer

Please feel free to reach me for further clarification in Open UI.